# MySQL Select last inserted records without primary ID or date field

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

```
Email, Flag1, Flag2
```

**The question:**
Is there any way i can do a select to get the last 100 inserted fields?

As i understand the table populates by adding new records with simple "insert" to the end of the table.

I have an idea how to do that in PHP+MySQL (the very ugly way: *SELECT ALL RECORDS*, *assign to each record autoincremented ID in php loop, and get the last 100 records.*)

**Is there more elegant way to do that with pure MySQL?**

Comment: you could add a `date` field and order `asc` by `date`, but why without primary `id` ?

Comment: Rows in a table have no order unless you impose one. There's simply no concept of "last" without some identifying attribute that you can sort on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not possible, because if you don't set a field with the timestamp or an autoincrement how will the system know the last inserted?.  so you have 2 easy options.

- Create a timestamp field: and when you make the order just make `select * from yourtamble order by timefield desc limit 100`
- Create a as ID with autoincrement.  The good about this is that you can have a primary key and know the exact order how the listing were inserted, the bad thing about this, is that you'll need another field time to know when the data were insert.  As the timestamp solution you could make `select * from yourtamble order by id desc limit 100`

Comment: Hm... if i add a timestamp field to the table with current timestamp as a default value, i won't have to make changes to existing code right?. I thing that might be helpful in a future.

Comment: @rinchik no, but your old data will have something like 0000-00-00 as value so you need yo edit it manually or recreate all the data, anyway make a backup of your APP and your DB (always is good to have a copy) and try it

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the last inserted records without a unique way to identify the row (such as an `id` or a `date`) since your index will sort based upon whatever primary key you have (assuming `Email` in this case).

Comment: this. plus your php loop will not work since you dont have a way to sort them by the "time" they got inserted, so incrementing an ID internally will not work.

Comment: did not mean to downvote, actually pretty sure i voted it up.

Comment: @Najzero Wasn't directed at you :)

Comment: Will i get last 100 records with the last in — first out technique? Meaning that if i will get last 100 records from the bottom of the table? I think that's possible with php.. no?

Comment: @RinatRUssenov On the database side, theoretically without an index it could be possible, however, the engine will typically create it's own index that will inevitably sort it.

Comment: @njk You meant that DB will mix all the records eventually?

Comment: @RinatRUssenov If your table has an index, the records will be sorted based on your primary key. This means that every time you insert a new record, it will be resorted or "mixed".