# how to fetch data just after insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting a row in mysql table and just after i try to get the inserted data auto incremented id. But unfortunately it doesn't works...

my code looks like-

```
$q4 = $query - > prepare('INSERT INTO tblstate(state, country_id) VALUES(:state, :country_id)', $con);
$res4 = $query - > InsertState($q4, $state, $country_id);

if (isset($res4)) {
    $q5 = $query - > prepare('SELECT * FROM tblstate WHERE state=:state', $con);
    $res5 = $query - > SelectState($q5, $state);
    $state_id = $res5['state_id'];

}
```

table structure is-

```
Table name: tblstate Fields: state_id(AUTO_INCREMENTED)(PK), state, country_id

function InsertState($q, $state, $country_id) {
    $q - > execute(array('state' => $state, 'country_id' => $country_id));
    return self::Result($q);
}

function SelectState($q, $state) {
    $q - > execute(array('state' => $state));
    return self::Result($q);
}
```

Comment: What driver are you using, there should be a last insert id function. A) http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php B) http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: mysql:PDO...  i'd already tried lastInsertId() but this didn't work..

Comment: What happened? Can you show usage, also possibly what `InsertState` does?

Comment: PDO doesn't have `SelectState` and `InsertState` so try again.

Comment: i updated the code..

Comment: @Hasan What variable did you try to call `lastInsertId` on?

Comment: $q6 = $query->prepare('select LAST_INSERT_ID() from tblstate ',$con);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the just inserted row of a MySQL table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712838/how-do-i-get-the-just-inserted-row-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: and one more thing.. the value of $state_id is null..i  don't know y?? :(

Comment: No idea what you are doing here. You made your own functions and don't care to show them so not much we can do. This `$query->prepare('select LAST_INSERT_ID() from tblstate ',$con); ` is incorrect in a number of ways, see the link I provided.

Comment: Nowhere in the sample code are you trying to get the last inserted ID. What are you actually trying? Show the code that isn't working, not code that is working.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you're using PDO.  Try:

```
$query->lastInsertId();
```

For more details, see the [documentation for PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).